# UIScrollView scrolls to different position if animated

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I've got a simple and yet difficult problem:

```
[self.scrollViewForKeyboard setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.contentOffsetYBeforeEditing) animated:NO];
[self.scrollViewForKeyboard setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.contentOffsetYBeforeEditing) animated:YES];
```

have a different effect at a certain point in my app: Not animating the content offset will scroll to the intended position, but changing the content offset with the animated flag set will make the `UIScrollView` scroll down too far. If I click/tap into the messed up `UIScrollView`, it will reset to the correct position set by the animation message above. If I animate the the scrolling by myself with an animation block, everything works fine.

The exact circumstances are way too difficult to explain here, cause the content I display is a bit complex, so my question is: Could it be possible, that the animation of the `UIScrollView` is somehow interfering with some other part of my app? What circumstances in genereal could cause such a behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely cause would be another animation happening at or near the same time affecting either the scroll view's frame or contentSize.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, since I am indeed animating content of the scroll view that changes it's `contentSize`. Nevertheless, I could fix the problem very simply: I just opted for the animation-block-option described in my initial question, and now everything works perfectly fine.